# Removing elements from string created with Array.join(' '). How can I keep the whitespace at the beggining?

Tags: javascript, input, whitespace

I have two `div`s. `Div` on the left is my input, `div` on the right is my prompt, where I display words that need to be typed in order.

On every keypress in input, the first character of the current word in prompt div is removed (provided that it is the same as the one I've just typed in input).

After I had typed within input all characters of the word given in prompt, I confirm that with pressing 'Space' and move on to the next word.

All goes well until the entire word was typed and suddenly there is no whitespace between content of input and the next word in prompt. It just disappears (note that the whitespaces between words come from the [separator] parameter in Array.join() I had used to display content in my prompt div.

I've already tried to `replace Array.join(' ') with Array.join('*')`. That solved my problem since asterisk does not disappear after typing the whole word, unlike my whitespace separator. However, I don't want my word to be separated with any 'symbol' other than whitespace.

I've also tried to use some sort of filter or modify my computed property, so that it starts with whitespace every time the first word becomes an empty string, but it doesn't work either.

```js
let animals = ['dog', 'horse', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cat'];

let animalsString = animals.join(' ');

document.querySelector('.animals-container').innerText = animalsString;

document.querySelector('.input').addEventListener('keydown', () => {

  let remainingChars = this.animals[0].slice(1);
  this.animals = this.animals.slice(1);
  this.animals.unshift(remainingChars);

  document.querySelector('.animals-container').innerText = this.animals.join(' ');
});
```

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
}

.input {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <input class="input">
  <p class="animals-container"></p>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zVmBjP

Expecting whitespace appearing between input `div` content and the first word of the prompt when the whole word has been typed.

Comment: Please provide [MRE]

Comment: I see a vue.js tag on this question yet this is not a vue.js problem, especially considering that the use of the document object (via the querySelector method here) is considered very harmful in vue.js. You should probably remove the tag.

Comment: @SamuelFaure you are right, the code I provided first was in Vue. However, after editing and providing minimal example, it became plain JavaScript. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @Łukasz You would probably benefit from using jsfiddle.net instead of codepen for showing MRE of a vue.js component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML does not display leading spaces. Use a non-breaking space instead.

In addition, you are removing an element from the array when the word has been typed - and therefore the whitespace between that element and the next disappears.

I would suggest using a string to track progress, not an array.

Try using this:

```
let animals = ['dog', 'horse', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cat'];

let animalsString = animals.join(' ');

document.querySelector('.animals-container').innerText = animalsString.split(" ").join("\xa0"); //Use non-breaking space

document.querySelector('.input').addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  var inputText = document.querySelector(".input").value
  if (!animalsString.startsWith(inputText)) {
    document.querySelector(".input").value = inputText.slice(0, inputText.length - 1)
  }
  document.querySelector('.animals-container').innerText = animalsString.slice(inputText.length).split(" ").join("\xa0"); //Use non-breaking space
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEqyRP